# How to get the element id when I browse a webpage

Tags: python, html

I want to get the element id when I click a button or something else in a webpage . How can i get it by Python or js?

Answer (score 0):

If by "get the element id when I click a button" you mean the id of the button then this is how you do it in javascript

```
 <button onclick="myFunction(event)" id="testBtn">Click me</button>
```

And inside your script tag

```
  function myFunction(event) {

console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
```

Comment: I can't edit the webpage, like the stackoverflow, I want  to get the element id when I click a button. Is there python code can do that?